# OpenSuSE removed netstat and ifconfig. What are the plans for ubuntu?

Tags: ifconfig, netstat

OpenSuSE removed netstat and ifconfig. What are the plans for Ubuntu?

Will Ubuntu remove these commands, too?

Comment: They're also not available by default in Ubuntu, one needs to install `net-tools` package.

Comment: @pomsky are there plans to deprecate net-tools?

Comment: No idea, sorry. If I'm not mistaken it's hardly maintained nowadays.

Comment: @pomsky "hardly maintained" is ok, as long as nobody wants to remove it.